# Link wrapped around image makes div slightly taller

Tags: html, css

How can I make the link around an image not add another pixel or two height to the image div?

This is the simple code:

```
<div><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></a></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xrGDv/

Image hosted by placekitten and taken by [Titran's Kasper](http://www.flickr.com/photos/35652310@N00/2734596155/)

Is there a dynamic way to do this? I.e not have to give the div a fixed height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a style rule to the image such as `display: block`, or `vertical-align: top`.

The image is an inline element and will display some white space beneath the baseline of the inline box that contains it.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/xrGDv/2/

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of vertical-align, that does the trick nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you just need to set `display: block` to img

http://jsfiddle.net/xrGDv/1/

If you need another content in div, try to set `float: left` to img, and `<div style="clear:both"` after content

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <style>
        a{margin:0;border:0;display:block;} 
        div {background-color:blue;}
    </style>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    </a>
</div>
```